# Renaming files based on parent dirrectory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to rename a set of files recursively using only the parent at a certain level. I have files in:

```
\test\d1\d2\d3\000.png
\test\d4\d5\d6\000.png
\test\d7\d8\d9\000.png
```

That should be converted to:

```
\test\d1\d2\d3\d1.png
\test\d4\d5\d6\d4.png
\test\d7\d8\d9\d7.png
```

Exploring recursively with for /R doesn't have a clear solution to get a higher level folder to rename as.

The 000.png is the only file and none are present in intermediate dirrectories.

I've been trying to use:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\test"
for /d %%P in (*) do for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%P"') do rename "%%F" "%%P_%%~nxF"
popd
```

from another thread, but am having trouble understanding what the script does.

Comment: Specify certain level, counted from top or from the file? Only file `000.png`? Are these files also present in intermediate folders? What is your code so far? [SO] isn't a script writing service.

Comment: The 000.png is the only file and none are present in intermediate directories.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\test"
for /d %%P in (*) do for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%P\000.png" 2^>NUL'
) do echo rename "%%~fF" "%%~nP%%~xF"
popd
```

- pushd stores current folder to a stack and changes to the given folder
- popd restores the old folder.
- the `for /d` iterates all sub folders from "C:\Users\test" using `%%P` that's your chosen name.
- the for /f parses dir output starting from that folder getting all 000.png files.
- `%%~nP` gets only the name of the folder (d1/d4/d7) using the `~n` modifier (see [for /?](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html))